# Call to a member function getInnerHtml() on a non-object

Tags: php

When I execute my script, I get a fatal error:

```
Call to a member function getInnerHtml() on a non-object in E：
```

this is my code:

```
$preg = preg_split('/<br>|<nobr>/', $DIV[1]->getInnerHtml());
```

then I check the $DIV[1]'s type with the function var_dump();

```
var_dump($DIV[1]);
```

and the result is:

```
object(htmlNode)[2331]
```

doesn't that mean that `$DIV[1]` is a object?

But the script still shows "Call to a member function `getInnerHtml()` on a `non-object`"?

Answer (score 1):

I think the `var_dump` is misleading. You might enter this code multiple times.

Add:

```
if (is_object($DIV[1]) === false) {
    var_dump($DIV[1]);
    exit;
}
```

`$DIV[1]` is probably undefined (so `null`) or it has a value you didn't expect, like `false.`

Comment: Thank you for your reminding! Because my code has a loop, and first time the $DIV[1] has values,but the second time, its value is null, so